# Gestures with WebView

Tags: java, android

What I'm trying to do:
I want the user to be able to custom gestures and name them "up","down"..etc. Then when the user runs my application, it loads up a WebView with a particular url like http://google.com. Then the user can draw the gesture he created earlier. So if he draws the "up" gesture, then another webview opens.

My problem:
When I try to draw the gesture over the webview, it doesn't draw. Rather it scrolls the webview.

What have I tried:
Already created a GestureOverlayView and put the WebView within that. Unfortunately, the GestureOverlayView is unable to detect the gestures as the WebView gets scrolled.

My Code:

```
public class WebViewCenter extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

GestureLibrary mLibrary;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
    //webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    //Button btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);
    //btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures_overlay);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);


    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://live.com");


}

public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    mLibrary.load();
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
    Log.i("Default Marker", predictions.get(0).toString());
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        String action = predictions.get(0).name;

        Log.i("Gesture", action);
        if ("up".equals(action)) {
            Log.i("Up_gesture", "Up gesture detected");
            Intent int_up = new Intent(WebViewCenter.this, WebViewUp.class);
            WebViewCenter.this.startActivity(int_up);
            //return true;
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Adding a contact", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        /*else
        {
            Log.i("Marker 2", "god knows what ur upto");

        }*/
    }
}
```

Any advice as to how can I separate the WebView scrolling from the gesture building?

Thanks,
Pawan

Comment: See the link . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229177/fling-gesture-and-webview-in-android

Comment: Thanks - just saw your reply.

Comment: The solution linked to adds fling capabilities but disables all default webview touch events like scroll and click. :(