# Android listview of webviews

Tags: android, listview, webview, swipe

first of all I am not sure if this is the right approach.

What I want to do is have a user experience where the user moves between webviews via swipes, and animating this transition, would I use a list of webviews or http://jquery.hinablue.me/jqiphoneslide/

thoughts?

Comment: If are looking for right / left swipes you should look at ViewFlipper or @CommonsWare extended it to use swipes or "flings" to trigger the change views ViewSwiper - https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper

Comment: I think this article will be useful for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229177/fling-gesture-and-webview-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean you want to move between WebViews using horizontal swipes? If so have a look at the ViewPager component in the Android support library here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: I haven't had a chance to use the ViewPager in the compatibility package yet, but I was still going to recommend it :-)