# Call Javascript Function from URL

Tags: javascript

The javascript below enables swipe left/right navigation. For some reason, I would like to call this function using URL such as `<a href="javascript:function">`. Certain URL will equivalent to left swipe, while another URL will equivalent to right swipe. Is this possible?

```
(function( window ){

var window = window,
    document = window.document,
    screen = window.screen,
    touchSwipeListener = function( options ) {
        // Private members
        var track = {
                startX: 0,
                endX: 0
            },
            defaultOptions = {
                moveHandler: function( direction ) {},
                endHandler: function( direction ) {},
                minLengthRatio: 0.3
            },
            getDirection = function() {
                return track.endX > track.startX ? "prev" : "next";
            },
            isDeliberateMove = function() {
                var minLength = Math.ceil( screen.width * options.minLengthRatio );
                return Math.abs(track.endX - track.startX) > minLength;
            },
            extendOptions = function() {
                for (var prop in defaultOptions) {
                    if ( defaultOptions.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
                        options[ prop ] || ( options[ prop ] = defaultOptions[ prop ] );
                    }
                }
            },
            handler = {
                touchStart: function( event ) {
                    // At least one finger has touched the screen
                    if ( event.touches.length > 0  ) {
                        track.startX = event.touches[0].pageX;
                    }
                },
                touchMove: function( event ) {
                    if ( event.touches.length > 0  ) {
                        track.endX = event.touches[0].pageX;
                        options.moveHandler( getDirection(), isDeliberateMove() );
                    }
                },
                touchEnd: function( event ) {
                    var touches = event.changedTouches || event.touches;
                    if ( touches.length > 0  ) {
                        track.endX = touches[0].pageX;
                        isDeliberateMove() && options.endHandler( getDirection() );
                    }
                }
            };

        extendOptions();
        // Graceful degradation
        if ( !document.addEventListener ) {
            return {
                on: function() {},
                off: function() {}
            }
        }
        return {
            on: function() {
                document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler.touchStart, false);
                document.addEventListener('touchmove', handler.touchMove, false);
                document.addEventListener('touchend', handler.touchEnd, false);
            },
            off: function() {
                document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handler.touchStart);
                document.removeEventListener('touchmove', handler.touchMove);
                document.removeEventListener('touchend', handler.touchEnd);
            }
        }
    }
    // Expose global
    window.touchSwipeListener = touchSwipeListener;

}( window ));



(function( window ){
    var document = window.document,
        // Element helpers
        Util = {
            addClass: function( el, className ) {
                el.className += " " + className;
            },
            hasClass: function( el, className ) {
                var re = new RegExp("\s?" + className, "gi");
                return re.test( el.className );
            },
            removeClass: function( el, className ) {
                var re = new RegExp("\s?" + className, "gi");
                el.className = el.className.replace(re, "");
            }
        },
        swipePageNav = (function() {
            // Page sibling links like <link rel="prev" title=".." href=".." />
            // See also http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html
            var elLink = {
                    prev: null,
                    next: null
                },
                // Arrows, which slide in to indicate the shift direction
                elArrow = {
                    prev: null,
                    next: null
                },
                swipeListener;
            return {
                init: function() {
                    this.retrievePageSiblings();
                    // Swipe navigation makes sense only if any of sibling page link available
                    if ( !elLink.prev && !elLink.next ) {
                        return;
                    }
                    this.renderArows();
                    this.syncUI();
                },
                syncUI: function() {
                    var that = this;
                    // Assign handlers for swipe "in progress" / "complete" events
                    swipeListener = new window.touchSwipeListener({
                       moveHandler: function( direction, isDeliberateMove ) {
                           if ( isDeliberateMove ) {
                               if ( elArrow[ direction ] && elLink[ direction ] ) {
                                   Util.hasClass( elArrow[ direction ], "visible" ) ||
                                       Util.addClass( elArrow[ direction ], "visible" );
                               }
                           } else {
                               Util.removeClass( elArrow.next, "visible" );
                               Util.removeClass( elArrow.prev, "visible" );
                           }
                       },
                       endHandler: function( direction ) {
                            that[ direction ] && that[ direction ]();
                       }
                    });
                    swipeListener.on();
                },
                retrievePageSiblings: function() {
                    elLink.prev = document.querySelector( "head > link[rel=prev]");
                    elLink.next = document.querySelector( "head > link[rel=next]");
                },
                renderArows: function() {
                    var renderArrow = function( direction ) {
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.className = "spn-direction-sign " + direction;
                        document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ].appendChild( div );
                        return div;
                    }
                    elArrow.next = renderArrow( "next" );
                    elArrow.prev = renderArrow( "prev" );
                },
                // When the shift (page swap) is requested, this overlay indicates that
                // the current page is frozen and a new one is loading
                showLoadingScreen: function() {
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.className = "spn-freezing-overlay";
                    document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[ 0 ].appendChild( div );
                },
                // Request the previous sibling page
                prev: function() {
                    if ( elLink.prev ) {
                        this.showLoadingScreen();
                        window.location.href = elLink.prev.href;
                    }
                },
                // Request the next sibling page
                next: function() {
                    if ( elLink.next ) {
                        this.showLoadingScreen();
                        window.location.href = elLink.next.href;
                    }
                }
            }
        }())

    // Apply when document is ready
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        document.removeEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false );
        try {
            swipePageNav.init();
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }, false );


}( window ));
```

Comment: "*I would like to call this function using URL*" - [Just don't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/245868/1048572).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that. However, if it is for organization goals why not have two JavaScript files, each one with its own namespace. If you do this, you call only that namespace expected for the link clicked.

Comment: The reason why I want this is I want to implement swipe navigation in android webview like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384638/implement-swipe-function-in-webview-and-call-a-javascript-function-via-a-javascr
The user who posted the question has function like javascript:left()

Comment: I got it. It is going beyond my knowledge. I can only suggest "javascript: left()" and inside of left function do a ajax and request the code. Once you have the code execute. Same for right.