# Android WebView pulling it multipe php pages that change based on user swipe

Tags: php, android, webview, swipe

I looked swipe , but I did not understand. i have php page. 
i want:
When the page opens (m.mydomain.com/content.php?id=13) if right touch id=12 if left touch 14.

I do not know where to write this is urls. and this is possible?

```
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl("m.mydomain.com");

            view.loadUrl(url);
//if right { view.loadUrl(m.mydomain.com/content.php?id=13-1) }
//if left { view.loadUrl(m.mydomain.com/content.php?id=13+1) }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: sorry my english very bad. i can't write.

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578895/how-to-detect-a-swipe-gesture-on-webview