# Two title bar issue with a webview

Tags: android

I have an Android app. I have put a WebView inside it and then it loads a website which is HTML5 based.

My problem is, The website itself has a menu on top right corner. And my native android app also have the title bar and menu on top right corner. I can hide the native title bar, but that way user will not be able to do any native app operations.. What will be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578895/how-to-detect-a-swipe-gesture-on-webview). You can initially hide the ActionBar and then register a listener on the WebView that listens for swipes down showing the ActionBar for a period of time before hiding it again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [javascript bridge](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) and from your webapp menu invoke native methods, then having only one menu.