# Android left/right swipe gesture in WebView activity (with clicking on links and vertical scrolling)

Tags: android, webview, swipe, gesture

SOLVED, solution is underneath.

I want to replace buttons for navigation in webview to 2 swipe gestures - left and right swipe. This [Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures) link really helped me, but I encountered problem - after implementing this code I was unable to click on links/ or scroll through loaded webpage in webview activity(I have used 1st answer from possible answers).

Then I found out that in another answer in this question is something similar - how to scroll in listview - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20005481/3272449, but I wasn't able to get it running. In logcat i get this debug info:
http://s27.postimg.org/5qfipgi1v/message.png

This is my OnSwipeTouchListener:

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public GestureDetector getGestureDetector(){
    return  gestureDetector;
}
}
```

And my webview activity(stripped):

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
private WebView browser;
    private OnSwipeTouchListener onSwipeTouchListener;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
            onSwipeTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
public void onSwipeRight() {
    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void onSwipeLeft() {
    Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
};

browser.setOnTouchListener(onSwipeTouchListener);
} // end of onCreate
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    onSwipeTouchListener.getGestureDetector().onTouchEvent(ev); 
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);   
}
} // end of WebViewActivity
```

How to make left/right swiping, vertical scrolling and clicking on links working at the same time?

SOLUTION: Same solved question:
 [Fling Gesture and Webview in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229177/fling-gesture-and-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with the `GestureDetector` to reliably diagnose your problem. One thing you could try is cloning the event:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    onSwipeTouchListener.getGestureDetector().onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(ev)); 
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);   
}
```

Failing that another way to approach this is to use [onOverScrolled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) instead of a `GestureDetector`:

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled (int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    if (scrollX > (getWidth() + THRESHOLD) && clampedX) {
        onSwipeLeft();
    }
    if (scrollX < - THRESHOLD && clampedX) {
        onSwipeRight();
    }
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);
}
```

This does assume that your content is not normally scrollable sideways though.

Comment: Adding MotionEvent.obtain(ev) doesn't change anything, there is still no vertical scrolling and debug output is same as previous.

Overriding onOverScrolled doesn't work, because this expect scrollable sideways. If I don't scroll to the side, then scrollX is still zero and onSwipeLeft/Right won't occur.