# Load next url when swipe in android

Tags: android, android-webview, swipe, gesture

I'm coding an android application. I have an array containing many url. I have loaded the first url on webview in mainactivity, and i want to load next url when i swipe. I'm using webview to load the url. So now I have to do as to how to load the next url by swipe

Comment: Set an touch listener to webview and process as u wish on swipe. But there is a problem the web site that u load may need some swipe to see whole data, so it is not good to override the touch of webview.

Comment: Thanks, so if i don't use webview, what i can to load url and swipe better webview

Comment: Did you tried this , pls look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565131/android-left-right-swipe-gesture-in-webview-activity-with-clicking-on-links-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Use [this library](https://github.com/aglover/gesticulate) and follow [this wiki](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Gestures-and-Touch-Events#swipe-gesture-detection) for easy gesture detect.

2- Get next item of array and load it to WebView.

Example code:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
  @Override
  public void onSwipeDown() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onSwipeLeft() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onSwipeUp() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onSwipeRight() {

    Iterator<String> it = al.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        yourWebView.loadUrl(it.next());
    }

  }
});
```

I don't have eclipse but it must be something like that.